# Command for running a rails task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What's the command if I wanted to run a task within test.rb under the following directory:

```
lib/tasks/lib/data/test.rb
```

Comment: `rake -T` would show you the list of available task(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a rake task you need to create a .rake file instead of .rb file in the lib/tasks directory as

```
lib/tasks/sample_task.rake
```

or in your case

```
lib/tasks/lib/data/test.rake
```

rake tasks are defined using namespace

Example test.rake file

```
# Namespace declaration
namespace :sample do

  # Task Description
  desc "Sample task"      
  # Here sample_task is the name of the task
  task sample_task: :environment do
     # Your task
     5.times do |t|
       puts "Hello world"
     end

  end

end
```

Now run your task with  `rake sample:sample_task` 
 where sample is namespace declaration and sample_task is the name of the task

If you are using rails 2 then you can use runner to run your tasks like

```
script/runner sample_task
```